# Is there a way to show total counts on Gmail's new inbox tabs?

Tags: gmail

The new tabs in Gmail's inbox show unseen counts, but is there a way to also show total counts?

[image]

The way I manage my email is to leave items in the inbox until addressed, but now I have to click through all five tabs to find if there's anything that I've missed. Having the total counts on the tabs will let me see this at a glance.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure exactly what you mean. Do you mean the ability to see how many are unread? If so you can do so by browsing on the left bar. You can click `more` and you will see all your categories. The categories name will list the number of unread emails beside it.

Example image:

[image: example]

Comment: When I click on each of the tabs, I see some number of messages.  They may be unread or read.  I'd like to know how many messages I'm going to see on the tab itself, i.e. Social (2), etc.

Comment: @dlanod You can't do this as of now...

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to the Gear menu on the right side of your screen
2. Go to Settings
3. Go to the Inbox panel
4. In the Priority Inbox options check **unread** from the list

You'll now be able to see the unread messages.